# How to convert coordinates received from CursorAnchorInfo class to Screen coordinates?

Tags: android, ime

When I am trying to access input field cursor x and y coordinates through CursorAnchorInfo class, I am receiving local relative coordinates and I need to convert that coordinates into screen coordinates.

I have checked for Matrix class to convert the coordinates to screen coordinates.

```
        float[] arr = new float[2];
        arr[0] = cursorAnchorInfo.getInsertionMarkerTop();
        arr[1] = cursorAnchorInfo.getInsertionMarkerHorizontal();
        Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
        cursorAnchorInfo.getMatrix().mapPoints(arr);
```

But above approach couldn't help me in getting correct coordinates.

Comment: is it identity matrix?

Comment: No, as per info provided in CursorAnchorInfo class it is a Transformation matrix that is applied to any positional information of this class to transform local coordinates into screen coordinates.

Comment: what do you see if you `Log.d` the value of that matrix?

Comment: on Log.d we get Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 45.0][0.0, 1.0, 84.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

Comment: Suppose, by calling respective methods arr = {50.0,39.0} and after calling mapPoints() it is changing to {95.0 123.0}

Comment: But it won't help me in getting screen coordinates.

Comment: change `arr[0]` with `arr[1]` and `arr[1]` with `arr[0]` - the first index is for `x` values and the second for `y` values

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Silly mistake from my end, thanks a lot.

Comment: sure, your welcome